# UIButton is unclickable after change in container height

Tags: ios, objective-c

An UIButton is contained inside a UIScrollView. I have this setup in a xib. I use a NSLayoutConstraint to change the height of the scrollview. After I click the button, the scrollview changes height, but then UIButton becomes unclickable.

Here is the code:

```
- (IBAction)TagPressed:(UIButton *)sender {

    if (self.height.constant == 200) {

       self.height.constant = 88;
    }else
       self.height.constant = 200;

    [self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];

    DRect(_scrollView.frame)
    DRect(self.view.frame)
    DRect(sender.frame)
    NSLog(sender.selected ? @"Selected" : @"Not Selected");
```

}

Drect is a nslog for frames. So the Console out is:

```
2013-04-08 17:04:19.264 TouchSelectApp[93618:c07] CGRect ( 20.000000, -112.000000, 62.000000, 200.000000)
2013-04-08 17:04:19.266 TouchSelectApp[93618:c07] CGRect ( 0.000000, 300.000000, 320.000000, 88.000000)
2013-04-08 17:04:19.266 TouchSelectApp[93618:c07] CGRect ( 7.000000, 78.500000, 48.000000, 44.000000)
```

Output from (lldb) po [[UIApp keyWindow] recursiveDescription]
I had to add a an extra button to create a debugging stop. The button I care about is inside SelectableTag.

```
$0 = 0x0887e0e0 <UIWindow: 0x7197a90; frame = (0 0; 320 568); autoresize = W+H; layer =    <UIWindowLayer: 0x7199620>>
   | <UIView: 0x719ed20; frame = (0 20; 320 548); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x719edd0>>
   |    | <UIRoundedRectButton: 0x719b9d0; frame = (51 464; 73 44); opaque = NO; autoresize = TM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x719baf0>>
   |    |    | <UIGroupTableViewCellBackground: 0x719c2a0; frame = (0 0; 73 44); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x719c370>>
   |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x719da50; frame = (1 1; 71 43); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x719dd20>>
   |    |    | <UIButtonLabel: 0x719d0f0; frame = (12 12; 49 19); text = 'Button'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x719d1e0>>
   |    | <UIView: 0x71a1160; frame = (0 300; 320 88); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x71a11c0>>
   |    |    | <SelectableTag: 0x719fcc0; baseClass = UIScrollView; frame = (20 -112; 62 200); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x71a04e0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x719fef0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
   |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x71a0c20; frame = (55 193; 7 7); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = TM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x71a0cc0>>
   |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x71a0dd0; frame = (55 62; 7 7); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = LM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x71a0e70>>
   |    |    |    | <UIRoundedRectButton: 0x719ddd0; frame = (-1 7; 64 44); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x719b630>>
   |    |    |    |    | <UIGroupTableViewCellBackground: 0x719d630; frame = (0 0; 64 44); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x719b690>>
   |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x719dea0; frame = (1 1; 62 43); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x719d990>>
   |    |    |    |    | <UIButtonLabel: 0x71a1630; frame = (12 12; 40 19); text = 'Test1'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x71a1e50>>
```

(lldb)

Comment: Get the button into an unclickable state.  Then pause in the debugger and run this: `po [[UIApp keyWindow] recursiveDescription]`.  Copy the output and paste it into your question.

Comment: @robmayoff I added the output to the original post. Thanks!

Comment: Which is the button you can't press?  The one labeled “Button” or the one labeled “Test1”?

Comment: @robmayoff "Test1" is the one I can't press. I just added "Button" for the breakpoint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the documentation of `hitTest:withEvent:` in the *UIView Class Reference*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-BBCCAICB):

> Points that lie outside the receiver’s bounds are never reported as hits, even if they actually lie within one of the receiver’s subviews. This can occur if the current view’s `clipsToBounds` property is set to `NO` and the affected subview extends beyond the view’s bounds.

The parent of your scroll view is the view with address `0x71a1160`.  Notice that the scroll view's `frame.origin.y` is -112. So the top 112 points of the scroll view are outside of its parent's bounds.  That part of the scroll view will never receive touches.  Your Test1 button is entirely in that part of the scroll view.

Comment: Move the parent view up 112 points and then move the scroll view down by the same amount.

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed this behavior too with UIButtons. After changing the frame of the parent view, if you add the button again it will work.

Comment: that seems like a hack. there must be a real reason for this.